# Regex: need help to meet 3 criterias

Tags: regex

could someone help my build a regex? It is for a username check

the requirements are

1. Alpha numeric
2. Any case
3. On - or a _ allowed from non alpha numeric set

Thanks,
Vidhu!

Comment: So, what have you tried? This problem could've been solved easily with a few Google searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following accomplishes all three:

```
[A-Za-z0-9\-_]*
```

Or better still:

```
[\w\-]*
```

Answer (score 3):

\w gives you any "word" character (number, letter, underscore of any case) and - is just a dash.

```
[\w-]*
```

http://www.rubular.com is a great site to test regular expressions. It has a good reference too.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should cover your requirements.

```
    ([a-zA-Z-_\d]*)
```